# getting nodal voltage in a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

OK this was one of my assignment question and i am baffled doing it. I am trying to get nodal voltage for this circuit since morning but its no help.

Please help me get nodal voltage for the following circuit where V1= 25 and V2= 7.

[image]

Comment: Redraw the circuit as four parallel branches using the site's built-in editor. Show your calculations and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is easily redrawn as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyWHsS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's now pretty clear that there is only one unknown node voltage to find. Everything else is definable, as shown.

So, the solution is easy. The currents spilling outward from \$V_x\$ are:

\$\frac{V_x}{R_1=5\Omega} + \frac{V_x}{R_2=2\Omega} + \frac{V_x}{R_3=3\Omega}\$

And the currents spilling inward from other nodes into \$V_x\$ are:

\$\frac{V_1=+25V}{R_1=5\Omega} + 10A + \frac{V_0=0V}{R_2=2\Omega} + \frac{V_2=+7V}{R_3=3\Omega}\$

These must be equal, of course, or else charge would pile up into the \$V_x\$ node. So:

\$\frac{V_x}{R_1=5\Omega} + \frac{V_x}{R_2=2\Omega} + \frac{V_x}{R_3=3\Omega} =
\frac{V_1=+25V}{R_1=5\Omega} + 10A + \frac{V_0=0V}{R_2=2\Omega} + \frac{V_2=+7V}{R_3=3\Omega}\$

\$V_x\cdot\left(\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}\right) =
\frac{25V}{5\Omega} + 10A + \frac{0V}{2\Omega} + \frac{7V}{3\Omega}\$

\$V_x =
\frac{5 + 10 + \frac{7}{3}}{\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}} = \frac{520}{31}V \approx 16.774V\$

I'm taking you at your word that you worked on it for a while. Hopefully, the above will then make some sense. It's very clear there is only one unknown node voltage. And it's very clear that the currents into and out of that node must be the same.

Personally, I don't like the usual way of instruction using nodal analysis. I prefer the above approach where I "see" currents as spilling away from it and into it. I keep track of things better that way. (It's yet another way to state the superposition principle.)